# Htaccess 404 & 301

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 404

The site runs on WordPress (latest) and is installed in `/htdocs/www/`. 
This htaccess file is in `/htdocs/www/roh/` along with a bunch of images and some CSS.

I want requests to the old html files to redirect to their new WordPress pages. I got most of it working, except the example below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /htdocs/www
ErrorDocument 404 /htdocs/www/
Redirect /roh/z1/q2lvl[1-9].html http://www.example.com/realms-of-hyrule/legend-of-zelda/maps
```

I go to `www.example.com/roh/z1/q2lvl2.html`, and it 404s and takes me to the main 404 page in my WordPress theme.

I tried ErrorDocument 404 `/htdocs/www/roh/404.html`, but that just got me an ISP redirected spam search page. The only way I got the main WordPress 404 page working was by going up directories until something worked. I do not want to send 404s to an `http://` address.

My questions:

1. Why doesn't the range of numbers `[1-9]` work?
2. Why can't I get `/htdocs/www/roh/404.html` working for anything in `/roh` and below?

Sorry for the basic questions, not exactly sure what to search for, so Google is only giving me examples I've tried or have working already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `RedirectMatch` directive instead. `Redirect` does strict string comparison while `RedirectMatch` uses regular expressions and therefore can be "dynamic".

   ```
   RedirectMatch 301 /roh/z1/q2lvl[1-9].html http://www.example.com/realms-of-hyrule/legend-of-zelda/maps
   ```

   BTW, if you are using `Redirect` and/or `RedirectMatch` directives only, then no need for `RewriteEngine` or `RewriteBase` (those are from 2 different modules).
2. Not sure -- but maybe because RewriteRules from folder above come into play... Rewrite debugging usually can shed some light on what is going on (it can show which 404 file Apache is trying to use, as rewrite rules got applied to it as well).. but for that you have to be able to edit server config or virtual host config.

Comment: Thanks much, that fixed it! :) If I can figure out the 404 page, will post back here. :)